# How to use for and foreach together

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have a number of files inside an array

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
```

I am counting this amount files as follows:

```
$total = count($files); // total of 4 files for example
```

But I'd like to understand how a for statement should be used in conjunction with the foreach

```
for ($x=1; $x<=$total; $x++) {
foreach($files as $file)
  {  
    echo "http://$file";
    echo $x;
  }
}
```

the result of this is:

```
name1  1
name1  1 
name1  1
name1  1

name1  2
name1  2
name1  2
name1  2

name1  3
name1  3
name1  3
name1  3

name1  4
name1  4
name1  4
name1  4

name1  5
name1  5
name1  5
name1  5
```

I would like the result to be

```
name1  1
name2  2
name3  3
name4  4
```

But I'm having difficulty understanding logic, about using foreach and for together.

Comment: Not possible, the foreach is a blocking call therefore it finishes then the for loop continues on to the next iteration.

Comment: I think what would be better would be a `while` then a `foreach` in that order?

Comment: You dont need a FOR to do what you are doing

Comment: you need either a for (counting the elements) OR a foreach (that doesn't requires to count the elements to iterate through theme)

Comment: To expand on what @RiggsFolly said, you can define a variable to keep count and increment it in within your `foreach`.

Comment: thank you all, I definitely did not know that it was possible to add an increment using the foreach

Comment: @Gislef it terms of it being possible or not, all you are doing is initialising a variable and incrementing its value. The `++` and `--` operators are not reserved for `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one or the other, you don't need both:

```
$x = 1;

foreach($files as $file)
{  
    echo "http://$file";
    echo $x++;
}
```

or

```
for($x = 0; $x < $total; $x++)
{
    echo "http://$files[$x]";
    echo $x + 1; // arrays are zero indexed, so need to add 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Increment `$x` parallel to outputting file name:

```
$x = 1;
foreach($files as $file)
{  
   echo "http://$file";
   echo $x;
   $x++;
}
```